# How to make a hollow square with words?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to create a program where I ask the user to input a string and I output a hollow square with the string. So an example would look like if the user input "four":

Output:

```
fourf
r   o
u   u
o   r
fruof
```

So far my code is this:

```
// JAVA code for hollow rectangle 
import java.io.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

class BasicAssign1 { 
  

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter line: ");
    String word = kb.nextLine();
    char abc[]={};
    int a=0;
    a=word.length();

    
    for(int i=0; i<=word.length()-1; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
      
      
    }
    

    
    int rows = word.length();
    int columns = word.length(); 
    int i;
    int j; 
    for (i = 0; i <=rows; i++) 
    { 

        for (j = 0; j <=columns; j++) 
        { 
          

            if (i == 0 || i == rows || j == 0 || j == columns) 
            {
              
              System.out.print(word.charAt(i));  
            }
            if( i==0 && j==columns){
              String word3 = "four";
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word3);
              sb.reverse();
              word3 = sb.toString();
              System.out.println(word3);
              
            }
            else   
                System.out.print(" ");             
        } 
        System.out.println(); 
    } 
    
    
     
} 
}
```

Currently this outputs:

```
fourf f f f fruof

o    o 
u    u 
r    r
```

Now I only got 1-2 rows properly done, but the 3rd row which is suppose to be in inverse is printed at the top and also isn't aligned to make a square. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: well i want to delete it but it wont let me

Comment: If you read the link Makyen posted yesterday, you will see that you cannot delete a question that has an upvoted answer. The sequence of events is that you posted a question and by doing so granted Stack Exchange the rights to distribute it (again, see above links). Then, someone experienced spent time and effort writing an answer for you, which was apparently well received by the community. You also accepted it indicating that it was a useful answer. To delete the question would also mean deleting the answer and throwing away that effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your task by noting that:

- first row = word + first letter of word
- second to length row = word[length-row], blank * length-1, word[row]
- last row = first letter of word + word backward

and writing a function to implement that e.g.

```
public static void square(String word) {
    int len = word.length();
    // first row: word + first letter of word
    System.out.println(word + word.charAt(0));
    // second to length row: word[length-row], blank * length-1, word[row]
    // create a blanks string
    String blanks = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(len - 1, " "));
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.println(word.charAt(len-i) + blanks + word.charAt(i));
    }
    // last row: first letter of word + word backward
    String reversed = new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(word.charAt(0) + reversed);
}
```

You can call this e.g.

```
square("four");
square("eleven");
```

Which will give the following output:

```
fourf
r   o
u   u
o   r
fruof

elevene
n     l
e     e
v     v
e     e
l     n
enevele
```